# How to return data from tables in MySQL that is not a table format?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've looked all over the Internet and even this website for an answer, and maybe I'm just phrasing my question in a way that isn't getting me to the correct results, but I was just wondering if there's a way to use SQL to return data from tables in a way that isn't table form?

Basically, I have a table of information on different books and I want to find a way to return info in this format: "Author; Title (Publisher: Year of publication)" without using PHP or any other type of programming language? Just using SQL?

Comment: Perhaps you could export your SELECT results into a cvs file then use a text editor like notepad++ and regex over it to format it the way you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use concat.

see example below

select concat(COALESCE(AUTHOR,''),'; ',COALESCE(TITLE,''),' (',COALESCE(PUBLISHER,''),':',COALESCE(YEAROFPUBLISH,''),')') as your_result from YOUR_TABLE

Comment: You'll also want to add a COALESCE(fieldname,'') on each of the fields that might have a null value in it, because concatenating anything with a null results in a null.

Answer (score 0):

This probably can help you.

```
select COALESCE(Author,'')+';'+COALESCE(TITLE,'') + ' ('+COALESCE(Publisher,'')+':'+cast([Year of publication]) as varchar) + ')' as Result from yourtable
```